# How to Change <script> id from with script - Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebug

I would like to change the id of a  tag from within the external script it points to.  What is the proper way of doing this?

Here is my script tag:

```
<script id="ID1" type="text/javascript" src="PATH_TO_EXTERNAL_JS"></script>
```

And here is what I'm trying to do from within my external script:

```
var sessionID = generateSessionID();
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var script = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
script.id = script.id + "_" + sessionID;
```

However, when I look at the live DOM tree in firebug, i see 2 scripts referenced in the DOM.  One with the original ID, and one with the new ID.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to change the ID of a specific script tag from within the script it points to, or are you looking for a method to put in any given external script that will identify and modify the tag that references it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute)

```
script.setAttribute("id", script.id + "_" + sessionID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You should modify Your code, to somewhat like this:

```
var i = 0
var sessionID = generateSessionID();
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var script = null;
for (i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++)
    if (scripts[i].src.toString() == 'PATH_TO_EXTERNAL_JS'){
        script = scripts[i];
        break;
    }

if (script)
    script.id = script.id + "_" + sessionID;
```

In other words. Get all the SCRIPT elements, iterate through this collection to look for an element that has some known attribute (src in this example) and if it's found, set it's new id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the old script, if your going to do it that way. Although Mike Lewis answer has a better method.

```
document.removeChild(originalScript)
```